# Yosemite won't prompt for 2 factor Auth code

Tags: apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I am not a macOS user but am trying to help my nephew.

On his 2014 Mac (running Yosemite, fully updated), he cannot connect to any sites requiring an Apple ID.

When he tries to, he's asked for his Apple ID and password.
He enters the password on the Mac and his phone prompts with a Deny/Allow access prompt; he hits Allow and is given a two-factor Auth code.

The problem is the Mac never prompts for the two-factor Auth code sent to his phone.

Comment: A 2014 Mac can most probably run a newer macOS.

Comment: ... and that's what we're trying to do, but to get Catalina from the Apple Store we first have to Authenticate his Apple ID, and we get the above problem. Is there a different way to download the installer and manually transfer it?

Comment: I should also mention the Apple website [How to get old versions of macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683).

Comment: What type of internal drive does your Mac have. I ask because HDDs do not work well with any version of macOS that requires APFS.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Thanks David, it's very responsive so I'd be very surprised if it's not an SSD, but I'll check.

Answer (score 4):

> Type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field.

The above answer came the excerpt given below. The excerpt is from the Apple website [Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915). *If you already entered the password, then try backing up and reentering the password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field.*

---

### What if I use two-factor authentication on a device running older software?

If you use two-factor authentication with devices running older OS versions—[like an Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation)](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT210092)—you might be asked to add your six-digit verification code to the end of your password when signing in. [Get your verification code](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204974#settingscode) from a trusted device running iOS 9 and later or OS X El Capitan and later, or have it sent to your trusted phone number. Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field.

Comment: Thanks, we tried that once or twice, it didn't work, and we didn't push it too much, it seemed like an odd workaround to me, which shows what I know. Well try it again.

Comment: One of the links given in my answer mentions needing at least El Capitan. You have Yosemite. You might try first downloading and installing El Capitan. You do not need any Apple ID or the App Store to download El Capitan. See [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) for instructions.